# Room: Receiving error when using @Transaction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm have a method annotated with @Transaction in my DAO class, which is causing the following error:

> A DAO method can be annotated with only one of the following:Insert,Delete,Query,Update

Here's my class:

```
@Dao interface Dao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE) fun insertList(chacaras: List<String>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM chacara WHERE cityId = :cityId")
    fun getListOfCity(cityId: String): LiveData<List<String>>

    @Delete fun deleteList(chacaraList: List<String>)

    @Transaction
    fun updateList(list: List<String>){
        deleteList(list)
        insertList(list)
    }

}
```

When I remove the method annotated with @Transaction it compiles normally.
Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

According to the [transaction documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction.html)

> Marks a method in an **abstract Dao class** as a transaction method.

Change your class to:

```
@Dao abstract class Dao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE) abstract fun insertList(chacaras: List<String>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM chacara WHERE cityId = :cityId")
    abstract fun getListOfCity(cityId: String): LiveData<List<String>>

    @Delete abstract fun deleteList(chacaraList: List<String>)

    @Transaction
    open fun updateList(list: List<String>){
        deleteList(list)
        insertList(list)
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@Query` be annotated with **Transaction** as well?

Comment: The key for me was to use `open` for the method, as I already had an abstract class.

Comment: @FirstOne exactly. methods are considered "final" in kotlin unless you explicitly define them as "open" methods.