# Room Dao Returns Insert IDs but Data is Missing from Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

When saving a list of objects in my room database using a Dao

```kotlin
@Insert()
fun saveCharmRankMaterialCosts(materialCosts: List<CharmRankCraftingCost>) : List<Long>
```

And this is used from my repository class to save results from an API call:

```kotlin
val charmRankCosts = CharmRankCraftingCost.fromJsonCraftingCost(
    charmRankId.toInt(),
    jsonCharmRank.crafting
)

// save crafting/upgrade costs for the rank
val results = charmDao.saveCharmRankMaterialCosts(charmRankCosts)
Log.d("CharmRepository", "Saved charm material costs: ${results.toString()}");
assert(!results.contains(-1))
```

When running this code, insert ID's are returned and the assertion is never triggered (i.e. no inserts fail).

But when I inspect the data base on the device, most of the supposedly inserted IDs are missing from the table. I'm very confused as to what is going on here. I've debugged this issue for many hours and have been unsuccessful in getting this to work. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you've inspected the exact database? Sometimes it happens when there is a mess in dealing with Device File Explorer, copying database file and so on. 2. Maybe there are another places in your code where you can change your database (in another thread), delete your inserted rows?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov I'm quite certain I'm looking at the right database but I will double check. I may also try using the data base inspector in android studio 4.1

Comment: As for deleting, I do clear the tables before saving the new items so maybe the delete functions are being called while content is being saved?

Comment: If you do clear before (in one thread or in one coroutine) it shouldn't affect. By the way from your code is not clear what you' re using to switch your db-operations from the main thread.

Comment: The code is inside my repository which is used in the view model which is accessed from a coroutine on the IO dispatcher in my view.

Comment: I looks like the data is saved correctly initially but then certain rows are deleted as more data is added.

Comment: As I understood your problem was not solved? Can you show code or just describe schema - how exactly you invoke delete- and insert- operation? Both calls from repository are inside one coroutine? And in addition - is your delete-operation conditional ("delete ... where ...") and you put there some parameter(s) or - you just delete all rows from the table before insert?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov correct it's not solved. I'll update the code, but I'm not deleting conditionally. I'm completely clearing tables before repopulating them with data that is pulled from an API.

Comment: can you post your entity and database file?

Comment: Any updates on your problem? Have you tried to delete and insert in one transaction?

Comment: @Gautam do you mean the data object and my room data base file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to have been related to foreign key constraints. I had a `CharmRank` data class with multiple related data objects. See below:

```
/**
 * Copyright Paul, 2020
 * Part of the MHW Database project.
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License
 */
@Entity(tableName = "charm_ranks")
data class CharmRank(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_id")
    var id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_id")
    var charmId : Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_level")
    var level: Int = 0, // 3

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_rarity")
    var rarity: Int = 0, // 6

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_name")
    var name: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "craftable")
    var craftable: Boolean
)
```

Each charm rank has associated skills and items to craft said rank. These objects are simply relational objects in that they hold the ID of the `CharmRank` and a `SkillRank` in the case of the skills object, or the ID of the `CharmRank` and the ID of the `Item` object.

```
data class CharmRankSkill(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_skill_id")
    var id: Int,

    var charmRankId : Int,

    var skillRankId: Int
)
```

```
data class CharmRankCraftingCost(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_crafting_cost_id")
    var id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_id")
    var charmRankId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "charm_rank_crafting_cost_item_quantity")
    val quantity: Int,

    val itemId: Int
)
```

Originally in `CharmRankCraftingCost`, I had a foreign key constraint on the `Item` object and the `CharmRank` object. Below is the foreign key constraint on the `Item` object:

```
ForeignKey(
  entity = Item::class,
  parentColumns = ["item_id"],
  childColumns = ["itemId"],
  onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)
```

The `Item` data object has IDs provided by the remote data source, so when I insert items into it's respective table, the conflict resolution is set to `Replace`. During the process of saving the relational items to the data base for the `CharmRanks`, I also have to save the `Item` objects prior to saving `CharmRankCraftingCosts`. It seems that what was happening is that when the `Item` objects are inserted, sometimes the items would get replaced, which would trigger the cascade action of the foreign key resulting in the `CharmRankCraftingCosts` items I just saved for the `CharmRank` to be deleted due to the cascading effect.

Removing the foreign key constraint on the `Item` table solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Your solution helped me, although in my case, the parent table referred to by the foreign key had an `@Insert` with the `REPLACE` conflict strategy which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from the comments, you make a delete before inserts. The problem is that it happens that the insert gets completed before the delete since you do them in separate threads. What you need is to do both in one transaction. Create a method in the the DAO class with @Transaction annotation (Make sure your dao is an abstract class so you can implement the body of this method):

```
@Dao
public abstract class YourDao{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    public abstract List<Long> insertData(List<Data> list);

    @Query("DELETE FROM your_table")
    public abstract void deleteData();

    @Transaction
    public void insertAndDeleteInTransaction(List<Data> list) {
        // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
        deleteData();
        insertData(list);
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730172/room-receiving-error-when-using-transaction) for Kotlin Version of the code.

Comment: I tried this and this did not resolve the issue. Even after making my save function non-suspend functions the behavior is exactly the same

Comment: Share your DAO and repository please. We need to see the way you delete from and insert in the db.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it is not related to how I'm deleting and inserting. It was actually due to foreign key cascade effects.

Comment: I will still award the bounty to your answer since you put forth effort to help me out. My answer, however, will be the accepted one. Thanks